# Mount internal HDD - folder location convention (unix)

Tags: linux, unix, mount

Is there an agreed convention exactly where to mount internal harddrives?
I read people use  `/mnt/` is used for external space like usb drives or portable harddisks.

Some people use `/usr/local/share/` for  their network shared folders, so is `/usr/local/` a good spot to mount a internal hdd or where would you suggest to mount to?

The files on the disk are media files, which I intend to share via network - think NAS.

Comment: `/usr/local/share/` is definitely **not** where you want to mount HDDs, if you follow the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRSHAREARCHITECTUREINDEPENDENTDATA) …

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29134/where-in-should-extra-disks-be-mounted/29135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what the internal hard drive is for. If it contains the root file system, mount it to `/`, if it contains the user directories, mount it to `/home`, if it contains data to be shared over the network mount is to `/export`. If you can't categorize it, create a new directory with a distinct name.

`/mnt` is used as a temporarary mount point. An internal hard drive is permanent, so that's the wrong place. `/media/` is often used for removable devices, but not for the internal ones.

Comment: I use /mnt/ now, but you make a good point since /mnt is used for temporary devices. The files are media related and intended to be shared over the network, is /home stil a good idea for that?

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/local/share` is for files

- placed by the local system administrator (as opposed to being placed
  by the distribution or a third-party application)
- and that are intended
  to be accessed by anyone on the system.

Examples are the HTML and script files that make up a locally developed or hand-installed web application.  At least that's what I always thought.

Best I can tell is to use `/mnt` for this purpose - make a directory that reminds you of the purpose or function of the drive and mount it there.

Comment: Right now I use /mnt. The file are all media files - think NAS, is it still a good idea to use that mount point?

Comment: Don't mount ON /mnt, but make a directory under /mnt and mount there: i.e. `mkdir /mnt/my_external_01` and then `mount -t ntfs /dev/disk/by-id/usb-{whatever} /mnt/my_external_01` or similar.  If your disk is NTFS or FAT32 you can use mount options to set the permissions for all files on the drive.

Comment: Thanks that's what I do. I meant under `/mnt/`  e.g. `/mnt/foldername`

Comment: Is it a good idea to mount `/mnt/foldername` and then add a symbolic link from `/mnt/foldername/media` to `/usr/local/share/media` and then share that?